# Deriving Milne's predictor of order four from extrapolation polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I would like to derive the following Milne's predictor formula of order four for the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ from an extrapolation polynomial of degree four. $$y_{n+1} = y_{n-3}+\frac{4h}{3}(2y_n'-y_{n-1}'-2y_{n-2}')$$

We use the following extrapolating polynomial $$y(x)=a+b(x-x_{n-3})+c(x-x_{n-3})(x-x_{n-2})+d(x-x_{n-3})(x-x_{n-2})(x-x_{n-1})+e(x-x_{n-3})(x-x_{n-2})(x-x_{n-1})(x-x_{n})$$

Since we want the predictor formula in the prescribed form I used the following information

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{At } x=x_{n-3}, y=y_{n-3}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}(x_{n-2},y_{n-2}) = f(x_{n-2},y_{n-2})\\
\frac{dy}{dx}(x_{n-1},y_{n-1}) = f(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})\\
\frac{dy}{dx}(x_{n},y_{n}) = f(x_{n},y_{n})
\end{eqnarray}

to obtain the following

\begin{eqnarray}
y_{n-3} = a\\
b+hc-h^2d+2h^3e = f(x_{n-2},y_{n-2})\\
b+3hc+2h^2d-2h^3e = f(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})\\
b+5hc+11h^2d+6h^3e = f(x_{n},y_{n})
\end{eqnarray}

However, I do not know how to solve for $b,c,d,e$ from the above three equations to obtain the required formula. Can someone help?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  Otherwise, why do you need to "derive" it in a particular way?

Comment: If you're not married to a particular derivation, then a nice general approach to finite difference formulas is given in Chapter 1 of [LeVeque's text](http://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/fdmbook/).  A very concise but practical reference is [this paper by Fornberg](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144596322507).

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Thanks for the response. Yes, it's a homework problem. I am supposed to derive it in this way.